# How to make links clickable in Bootstrap via mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that works fine normally but when in mobile mode, all the links (with exception of the navigation) are no longer clickable. Does anybody know how to change this? I'm not too familiar with Bootstrap though I've tried to troubleshoot as much as I can.

Here's the website: http://dominiquehall.com/dom/

Thank you in advance if anybody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following code from your theme css file (agency.min.css) at line 477:

```
   div {
height: 100%;
}
```

Or you can override that property by adding the following code in your custom css file:

```
div{
height: auto !important;
}
```

The problem in your code is with the property of div having height 100%, thus overlaying all the links. The div containing the image of a person playing guitar is covering the links in mobile mode. The images are hidden but the div still exist.

Another hack is hiding that particular div in mobile mode.

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px)
{
  .target_div{
     display: none:
  }
}
```

In your case the target div is:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5">
          <div class="fixed">

          <img src="./img/dom1.jpg" id="photo" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" alt="">

      <a href="file:///Users/kelseygraham/Desktop/dom3/pdf/resume.pdf" id="bottom-left" class="btn hidden-sm hidden-xs">View Resume</a>

<a href="file:///Users/kelseygraham/Desktop/dom3/pdf/equipment.pdf" id="bottom-right" class="btn hidden-sm hidden-xs">Equipment List</a>
                </div>
         </div>
```

Just add a class name to the above div and a display as none for mobile devices and your site is good to go.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much! Worked perfectly.